# mbed + platformio.org: advice?

Tags: stm32, mbed

I am attempting to get the most basic (blinky) code to run on a STM32F401 Nucleo board.  Current status:

1. RUNS: out-of-box blinky code (responds to pushbuttons)
2. RUNS: mbed.org online-compile of simple blinky code (~13k bin, blinks as expected)
3. FAIL: platformio-compiled bin is almost 30k and does not blink the lights.  Same source code as #2

ini file is as follows:

```
[env:f401]
platform = ststm32
framework = mbed
board = nucleo_f401re
```

How do I get #3 to work?  What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I have same problem as you - how does one use platformIO with mbed? what do I flash?

Comment: Why use platformIO? If you want to compile offline just use mbed CLI.

Comment: Getting support for mbed directly has been really unpleasant.  Ivan and platformio are friendly and approachable.  That said, rather than bug him, I bit the bullet and really am trying mbed-cli these days.  I hope you and he can work together.

Answer (score 1):

It depends, platformIO may not be using mbed, it may be using the STM32Cube, in which case the source code using the mbed SDK wouldn't work.

Comment: I have a high confidence it is using the MBED framework.  It compiles, and when I look at the .pioenvs area I see a bunch of FrameworkMbed folders